# Struts2 xml validation for checkbox not for checboxlist

Tags: struts2, xml-validation

I have one form containing one checkbox(not checkbox list)and one textfield.
If the checkbox is cheked then no need to enter the value for textfield.
If the check box is not checked then I need to validate the textfield has mandatory.
How can I do using expression validator.Is this Possible in struts2.0.11.

Let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[fieldexpression validator](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/fieldexpression-validator.html)**. Example :

**SomeAction.java**

```
private SomeObject object; // with getter & setter
private boolean doNotCheck; // with setter
```

**input.jsp**

```
<s:textfield name="object.field" />
<s:checkbox name="doNotCheck" />
<s:fielderror fieldName="object.field" />
```

**SomeAction.validation.xml**

```
<validators>
    <field name="object.field">
        <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
            <param name="expression">
                <![CDATA[ isDoNotCheck() ? true : (object.field != null && !object.field.isEmpty()) ]]>
                <!-- OR -->
                <!-- isDoNotCheck() ? true : !object.field.isEmpty() -->
            </param>
            <message>This is a mandatory field</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `validate()` method in your action class and add the validation code in it.
For details, please read the docs.
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/form-validation.html

Another option is xml validation.
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your answer.But I did not find the answer for the scenario explained above in xml validation. If you provide with an example is very help full. thanks

Comment: Read the parts about expression validation and non field validators. You can use it to combine criteria and form the predicate. http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/using-non-field-validators.html